# Can't get video.js volume control to work

Tags: javascript, video, video.js, mute

I am using the video.js player to playback a video with newsitems. I need to have the volume muted, but can't get that to work.

My code is as follows:

```
<head>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js">
</script>
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://www.nujournaal.nl/feeds/flvsmall.xspf") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $videoloc = $xml->tracklist[0]->track[0]->location;
?>
</head>
<body>
<video id="Video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="1024" height="578"
    data-setup='{"controls" : false, "autoplay" : true, "preload" : "auto", "muted" : true}'>
    <source src="<?php echo $videoloc ?>" type="video/x-flv">
</video>
</body>
```

Firt I load the video.js library, then I have to use some php to extract the (daily changing) location of the video.

In the last part is the code I use to play the video. I included "muted" : true, but that doesn't affect the volume; it starts playing at 100%.

Any suggestions would be very welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the "muted" option like this :

```
<video id="Video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" muted controls="false" autoplay="true" preload="auto" width="1024" height="578">
<source src="<?php echo $videoloc ?>" type="video/x-flv">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
When trying, I notice that I get a black region of the defined size, with in the bottom a playbutton, a scrollbar and a muted speaker-icon. However, I can't get the video to play. Changing controls from false to true doesn't affect the behaviour. Same for autoplay. I can only get the video to play when adding the data-setup='{}' part... 
Any further idea's...?
(see http://www.bccnet.nl/services/nujournaal-1024-578-2.php, original one is without the last -2)

Comment: I see an error concerning the **mime types**, you can add on your `.htaccess`

`AddType video/x-flv  .flv
AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm`